# automatic or Inline spell check in TexnicCenter for latex files

Tags: spell-checking, texnic-center

I recently started using TexnicCenter after using winshell for several years. The spell check in Texniccenter has to be invoked manually which is tedious. Is there a way to enable inline or automatic spell check in Texnicceneter?

Answer (score 6):

I found how to do it.

In menu Tools->Options->Spelling, check the box "Check spelling while typing"

Comment: Funny - that's the first thing I searched for, so that I could **turn it off**!  To me, spell-checking should be a separate process from writing, in that the little notifications are distracting from the process of getting the words out there.  Also: I'm writing a PhD thesis in UK English but have numerous quotations in US English.  So, spell-check is frequently wrong about the spelling.

Comment: You should flag this question as answered, rather than simply adding an answer and letting the question sit about.